# Parts of form not getting displayed when visible set to true

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

My program is in a post release state so please bear with me.

## Scenario

My program is based on multiple layouts for different pages of different function for an office data management system (vehicle maintenance oriented). A major category of those functions is obviously data entry. I have used different styles to suite different audiences.

Getting to the point, one of the interfaces has excel styled grids and 3 buttons for Print/Save/Reset functions. I use FastReports for the form prints.

I am developing a custom class for the grid columns to make them accommodate a predefined list of controls instead of their cells on the fly but for now i just made the required controls children of the cells  in code.

The page has 3 sections (layouts);

- The top one is a kind of a purpose (Add/Modify/Add Partial) selector specific to all pages and may not be visible where not required.
- The Middle one is a control for receiving receipt nos of the forms to be modified, their information embedded in others etc. Its mostly on every page but not all.
- The Last one has the page's content which is the grid and the 3 buttons as mentioned earlier.

## Code

This is a snippet of code for displaying one of the problematic pages. It is executed when all data processing has been done with and the server OKs the transition.

### Legend

- **AState** : State Machine State Variable; Signifies the current state of the page displayed.
- **AMode**  : State Machine State Enumerator; Signifies the mode of the application as a whole, e.g. Booking (Data entry) etc. I have skipped the code involving this as it gets skipped during the transition of AState for this problem to occur.
- **fMode** : Same as above but its the main field of the form for the purpose.
- **UI_CA_Controls1** : The layout which contains the booking mode's purpose selector (Combo List Box).
- **EV_Mode** : A variable for convenience; It stores the Item Index of the purpose selector.
- **UI_CA_Grid** : The Layout contained in UI_CA_Content and itself contains UI_CA_FieldGrid (TGrid).
- **fEditColumn** : The second column of the grid having TEdits.
- **fGridDataset** : The grid associated TStringList.

//

```
procedure TUI.SetFormState ( AState : Byte; AMode : TMode = UIM_Unselected );
var
  EV_Mode, I : Byte;

begin

  
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  fFormState          := AState;

  // The children of the grid cells
  
  fCalEdit1.Parent    := nil; // Calender Edits
  fCalEdit2.Parent    := nil;
  fVehicleClass.Parent := nil; // Combo List Boxes
  fEmployee1.Parent   := nil;
  fEmployee2.Parent   := nil;
  fEmployee3.Parent   := nil;
  fEmployee4.Parent   := nil;

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  if AState = 0 then
  begin
  
    for I := 0 to 20 do
      DPCM.fGridDataset.Strings [I] := ''; // The Grid Associated TStringList

    UI_CA_ReceiptNo.ReadOnly  := False;
    UI_CA_ReceiptNo.Text      := '';

  end;

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  UI_CA_Content.BeginUpdate;

  case fMode of

    // Skipped unrelated modes

    UIM_Booking :
    begin

      UI_CA_Controls1.Visible := True;
      EV_Mode := UI_CA_EV_ModeSelect.ItemIndex;

      // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

      if fFormState = 0 then
      begin

        // Skipped handling of other EV_Mode values

        if EV_Mode < 7 then
        begin

          UI_CA_ReceiptControl.Visible  := True;
          UI_CA_Content.Visible         := False;

        end;

      end

      // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

      else if fFormState = 1 then // The problematic area
      begin

        if ( EV_Mode = 3 ) or ( EV_Mode = 4 ) then
        begin

          UI_CA_FieldGrid.RowCount := 6;
          UI_CA_Grid.Height        := 160;

          fCalEdit1.Parent        := fEditColumn.CellControlByRow ( 0 );
          fCalEdit1.Date          := Date;
          fCalEdit2.Parent        := nil;
          fVehicleClass.Parent    := fEditColumn.CellControlByRow ( 2 );
          fVehicleClass.ItemIndex := 0;

        end;
    
        UI_CA_Content.Visible := True;

      end;

    end;

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

  end;

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Workaround 1
  
  if UI_CA_Content.Visible then
  begin

    UI_CA_FieldGrid.UpdateColumns;
    UI_CA_Content.EndUpdate;
    UI_CA_FieldGrid.SetFocus;
    UI_CA_C2_Reset.SetFocus;
    UI_CA_C2_Print.SetFocus;
    UI_CA_C2_Save.SetFocus; 
    UI_CA_FieldGrid.SetFocus;

  end
  else UI_CA_Content.EndUpdate; 

end;
```

### The Problem

The problem is that whenever the receipt section is displayed the content section doesn't get displayed on the spot. The behavior is such that when i hover the mouse where those children controls and the 3 buttons should be they get displayed but the grid gets displayed when I click on it only.

The problem has arose by itself with no change in UI code which has baffled me for 3 days now. I have only made optimizations to protocol and data handling on the network side (Separate Data Module).

### Sequence

- The user wants to modify already booked vehicle's data.
- The user enters the booking receipt no. ( AState = 0, AMode = UIM_Booking )
- The client query's the server and the server replies with the complete dataset if exists.
- The client takes the data and copies it in the strings of the Grid associated TStringlist and the children fields.
- The client doesn't display the grid with the data and the 3 buttons. ( AState = 1, AMode = UIM_Booking )

## What have I tried till now

- Used BeginUpdate/EndUpdate which made it worse with alignment artifacts.
- Used SetFocus on the grid and the buttons which resulted in random display of some of them and sometimes complete display but not every time.
- Used Application.ProcessMessages with no change rather the UI thread sometimes just got stuck in it never to return. Used it in a separate thread, calling it every second with no change.
- Used a separate thread for the method with even more issues.
- Back tracked and restored old working code with no change (made me really angry).
- Update 1: I have tried to make the grid invisible and then visible at the end of the code. Now some cells of the grid get shown randomly.

## Workaround 1

- The grid and buttons can be shown when the SetFocus method is called for each of them.
- The order of the calls is erratic for the buttons. Like I had to call reset first and then print and save's SetFocus method otherwise only one of them got displayed.
- There is a split second realignment glitch which shows the controls resizing but i think that's ignorable.

## Workaround 2

- Do queued repainting rather than immediate. It doesn't have any caveats but the catch is after all that there is a delay in between every repaint.
  Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8424750/1388291

So if you people have any suggestions, I'll be really grateful.

Comment: This very same problem I got in the IDE when I attached a XP manifest to the Delphi 7 executable (delphi32.exe), running on Win7.

Comment: Well I haven't done anything such, if it happens automatically somehow, can you point to it, specifically. Because I have always kind of ran away from a solution requiring manifests.

Comment: On first look, it seems like you have issues with initially setting `Parent` property of various components to `nil` and then changing it based on `AState`/`AMode`. Double check your logic to see if it really does what is expected. Run your code step-by step and monitor the behavior. Replace constant values in `if` and `case` segments with real constants to avoid any confusion. If nothing helps, check if your Windows is a Professional version. There are known (and unknown) display issues with it.

Comment: There is no problem with parents changing as it does it correctly. Only the controls don't get displayed, the parents also! Also I have tried changing parents for each control separately with no change. I have Windows 7 x64 Ultimate running.

Comment: Two approaches to try and get this solved: 1. make a reproducible case that is as small as possible, then post it somewhere; 2. shelve your current sources, restore from a working version in your version control system, then diff the two, and re-apply the changes one-by-one until you found the problem.

Comment: I have struck a workaround briefed in the post after some fiddling with some not so obvious methods. @JeroenWiertPluimers 1) That's the problem, it doesn't show up in a smaller case where there are less controls getting hidden/unhidden. 2) Tried that, no results, it was like something changed in the project files or the ide that this started... Thanks for the reply though.